# Why addEventListener not working with id attribute

Tags: javascript

I want to add an "active" class on the button when I click the button but addEventListener is not working. I want to have a unique id for each of my  and

. data has the API response and I want to display the name from API on the button and email and other details on

Please help to understand

```js
window.onload = function() {

  //function send_with_ajax(){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      try {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // For IE 
      } catch (exception) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // For IE 
      }
    } else {
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  } else {
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP Request...!");
  }
  xhr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", true); // Make sure file is in same server
  xhr.send(null);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      //console.log(data);
      var sidebar = document.querySelector("#sidebar");

      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // data.map(function(){ 
        sidebar.innerHTML += "<button id='accordion" + i + "'>" + data[i].name + "</button>";
        sidebar.innerHTML += "<p id='panel" + i + "'>" + data[i].email + data[i].address.city + data[i].company.name + "</p>";

        var accordion = document.getElementById('accordion' + i);

        var panel = document.getElementById('panel' + i);

        accordion.addEventListener('click', function() {
          var active = accordion.classList.toggle("active");
          //console.log(accordion.classList.contains('active'));

          if (active) {
            panel.style.display = "block";
          } else {
            panel.style.display = "none";
          }
        });
      } // i for loop ends here
    }; // readystate
  }; //      onreadystatechange
} // onload
```

```html
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

Comment: `<javascript>` isn't an HTML tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're writing to `.innerHTML`, which completely replaces all of `#sidebar`'s contents, therefore removing all currently bound events.

Basically, you end up with one event bound, on the very last button, as it's added in the last iteration.

To keep the events on existing DOM, create the elements as nodes and append them.

Working example:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  //function send_with_ajax(){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      try {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // For IE 
      } catch (exception) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // For IE 
      }
    } else {
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  } else {
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP Request...!");
  }
  xhr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", true); // Make sure file is in same server
  xhr.send(null);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      //console.log(data);
      var sidebar = document.querySelector("#sidebar");
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        
        const accordion = document.createElement('button');
        accordion.id = 'accordion' + i;
        accordion.classList.add('active');
        accordion.innerText = data[i].name;
        sidebar.appendChild(accordion);
        
        const panel = document.createElement('p');
        panel.id = 'panel' + i;
        panel.innerText = data[i].email + data[i].address.city + data[i].company.name;
        sidebar.appendChild(panel);
        accordion.addEventListener('click', function() {
          var active = accordion.classList.toggle("active");
          if (active) {
            panel.style.display = "block";
          } else {
            panel.style.display = "none";
          }
        });
      } // i for loop ends here
    }; // readystate
  }; //      onreadystatechange
} // onload
```

```html
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

---

Note: While the snippet above does explain what's going on, I don't recommend it, other than for learning purposes. In a production website you'd bind only one `click` on `#sidebar`, check if the click was performed on an "accordion" button, if so find the corresponding panel by `id` and toggle it.

This way your function will work even on elements appended to DOM after you've added the listener.

Example:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  // we bind right from the start, `#sidebar` is empty
  document.getElementById('sidebar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON' && e.target.id.startsWith('accordion')) {
      const id = e.target.id.replace('accordion', '');
      const panel = document.getElementById(`panel${id}`);
      if (panel) {
        panel.style.display = e.target.classList.toggle("active") ? 'block': 'none';
      }
    }
  })
  
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      try {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // For IE 
      } catch (exception) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // For IE 
      }
    } else {
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  } else {
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP Request...!");
  }
  xhr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", true); // Make sure file is in same server
  xhr.send(null);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

      var sidebar = document.querySelector("#sidebar");
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        
        const accordion = document.createElement('button');
        accordion.id = 'accordion' + i;
        accordion.classList.add('active');
        accordion.innerText = data[i].name;
        sidebar.appendChild(accordion);
        
        const panel = document.createElement('p');
        panel.id = 'panel' + i;
        panel.innerText = data[i].email + data[i].address.city + data[i].company.name;
        sidebar.appendChild(panel);
      }
    };
  };
}
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

Funnily enough, this second solution also works when updating `#sidebar`'s contents with `.innerHtml += '...stuff'`, but I still wouldn't recommend it. Replacing all the sidebar contents in each iteration is way too aggressive, IMHO.

---

Thinking about how this code could be further improved, I'd skip setting the `display` property on panels via JS, for two reasons:

- `display` is not animatable (I won't cover animations here)
- out of principle: whenever you can do something using CSS, don't do it with JavaScript. This will keep your apps lightning fast.

When you start playing with animations you'll find it's significantly easier from stylesheet than from JS, as they typically imply changing multiple style properties).

In this case, I would use the fact the buttons are followed in DOM by the panels and toggle panels on/off via CSS:

```
#sidebar p { display: none; }
#sidebar button.active + p { display: block; }
```

Not only you skipped having to change the `style` property of the panel via JS, but you can also skip the query for finding it in DOM, so you also don't need to perform the replacement on the button's string `id`.  The entire listener becomes:

```
document.getElementById('sidebar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON' && e.target.id.startsWith('accordion')) {
    e.target.classList.toggle("active");
  }
})
```

*Note*: in this particular example the difference in performance is ***really*** insignificant. It's so small it's not measurable.
But what you should take from it is the way of looking at JavaScript code: always ask yourself: can I do this by running less code and/or by being less invasive?

```js
window.onload = function() {

  const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
  sidebar.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON' && e.target.id.startsWith('accordion')) {
      e.target.classList.toggle("active");
    }
  });

  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(data => data.forEach(
      ({id, name, email, address, company}) => {
        const accordion = document.createElement('button');
        accordion.id = 'accordion-' + id;
        accordion.innerText = name;
        sidebar.appendChild(accordion);
        
        const panel = document.createElement('p');
        panel.id = 'panel-' + id;
        [email, address.city, company.name]
          .forEach(el => appendSpan(panel, el));
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.appendChild(panel);
        sidebar.appendChild(div);
        setTimeout(() => {
          document.getElementById(`accordion-${id}`).classList.add('active')
        }, 120 + 21 * (data.length - id))
    })
  )
}

function appendSpan(parent, text) {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerText = text;
  parent.appendChild(span);
}
```

```css
#sidebar {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#sidebar button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 1.5rem 0 0 2rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
#sidebar div {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .35s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, .3, 1);
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: -.5rem .5rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), 0 1px 1px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 7%), 0 2px 1px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 6%);
}
#sidebar button.active + div {
  max-height: 50px;
}
#sidebar p {
  display: flex;
}
#sidebar p span {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  max-width: 24%;
  display: block;
}
#sidebar p span:first-child {
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 42%;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your reply and making the code very clear and understandable. What is the industry approach? What would you recommend?

Comment: The second snippet is "production ready" from DOM manipulation pov. I already explained why it's better. Obviously, it has virtually no styling and no UX (you'd need animations and whatnot) but that's outside of this question's scope, obviously. It's also as efficient as it could get (minimal amount of work for the browser, considering the task). Another good principle it follows is: it delegates the click event to the closest "permanent" parent. When you bind on document, the check is performed on every single DOM click. Which is suboptimal.

Comment: I am so glad for the explanation. thank you